Can I somehow do transitive extends?
I have classes
// Model which reads from DB
class LibModel {
  id: number;
  find<T extends LibModel>(params: Partial<T>): T {
    return params as T; // Dummy implementation, in reality reads from DB
  }
}

// Model for all priority queues
class PriorityQueueModel extends LibModel {
  priority: number;
}

class AmazonQueueModel extends PriorityQueueModel {
  amazonId: number;
}

class EbayQueueModel extends PriorityQueueModel {
  ebayId: number;
}

I want to pass them into a generic class that would return ebay/amazon specific items
// Governs all models of all types
abstract class BaseRepository<T extends LibModel> {
  Model: T;
  constructor(Model: T) {
    this.Model = Model;
  }

  public findById(id: number) {
    return this.Model.find({ id });
  }
}

// Governs just priority queue models
class GenericQueueRepository<
  R extends typeof PriorityQueueModel
> extends BaseRepository<R> {}

const AmazonPriorityQueue = new GenericQueueRepository<typeof AmazonQueueModel>(
  AmazonQueueModel
);
const amazonItem = AmazonPriorityQueue.findById(1); // { priority, amazonId }

Now the problem I am facing is Type 'R' does not satisfy the constraint 'LibModel'. This is weird, since R extends (PriorityQueueModel extends LibModel), but it seems type inference is not transitive. When tested with // @ts-expect-error, the code works.
Is there a way to make it transitive? Or is there some reason it's actually a good thing I can't do that?

Please [edit] to make the code a [mre] that demonstrates what you're seeing if we drop it into our own IDEs, without having unrelated problems. Right now I get a lot of errors about --strict mode violations (are you not using --strict in your compiler options? If not, ), and LibModel is not defined, so we're kind of stuck at the start.

Thanks for the feedback @jcalz, I have edited the code. Now just copy-paste it in sequence into editor.

You've got typeof in there. So this has nothing to do with "transitive" extends, since typeof X and X are generally different types. What are you trying to do? AmazonQueueModel the constructor of the class has no find method, you'd need new AmazonQueueModel as shown here (and still, not --strict? why?). Are you aware of the difference between class constructors and their instance types? It's hard for me to see here whether you intend to pass in constructors or instances
